# Oracle auto self join?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a query in Oracle. The result of this query should be list of 'child' tables of parent table:

```
WITH tempTab AS
 (SELECT owner          ,
         constraint_name,
         table_name
 FROM    sys.all_constraints
 WHERE   owner           = 'PARENT_OWNER'
 AND     table_name      = 'PARENT_TABLE'
 AND     constraint_type = 'P'
 )
 ,
 acTemp AS
 (SELECT DISTINCT ac.owner                       AS child_owner,
                                   ac.table_name AS child_table,
                                   ac.constraint_name
                  FROM             sys.all_constraints ac,
                                   tempTab tt
                  WHERE            ac.constraint_type   = 'R'
                  AND              ac.r_constraint_name = tt.constraint_name
 )
SELECT act.child_owner,
   act.child_table
FROM   acTemp act
```

And it works properly (I get some rows). But when I modificate few last lines (last SELECT) of this query:

```
WITH tempTab AS
 (SELECT owner          ,
         constraint_name,
         table_name
 FROM    sys.all_constraints
 WHERE   owner           = 'PARENT_OWNER'
 AND     table_name      = 'PARENT_TABLE'
 AND     constraint_type = 'P'
 )
 ,
 acTemp AS
 (SELECT DISTINCT ac.owner                       AS child_owner,
                                   ac.table_name AS child_table,
                                   ac.constraint_name
                  FROM             sys.all_constraints ac,
                                   tempTab tt
                  WHERE            ac.constraint_type   = 'R'
                  AND              ac.r_constraint_name = tt.constraint_name
 )
SELECT act.child_owner,
   act.child_table
FROM   acTemp act ,
   acTemp act2,
   tempTab tt
WHERE  tt.owner      = act2.child_owner
AND    tt.table_name = act2.child_table
```

I do not get any row. Why? In the second query I do not filter act table so the results should be the same as in the first query, but they are not.

Comment: First point - take some time to learn to use ANSI join syntax; it is a LOT easier to understand a query when it is written like this. Second point - I don't think your query does what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
     parent_table.owner
    ,parent_table.table_name AS parent_table
    ,child_table.table_name AS child_table
    ,parent_table.constraint_name AS constraint_name
FROM sys.all_constraints parent_table
INNER JOIN sys.all_constraints child_table ON ( child_table.constraint_name = parent_table.r_constraint_name AND child_table.owner = parent_table.owner)
WHERE parent_table.owner = 'PARENT_OWNER'
AND parent_table.table_name = 'PARENT_TABLE'
AND parent_table.constraint_type = 'R';
```